# Placing a value at a given location in an array method?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a method which places a given value at a certain location in an array.

This is my code. The increase is a function that double the length of the array store.

My problem is not with the increase function.

The issue I am having is that when I place a value in the index the value that was previously there is erased what I want to do is keep it, and at the same time keep the value I placed in the index.

```
public void addLoc (int index , Object obj)
{
    if(store.length - size <=4)
    {
        store=increase(store);
    }
    store[index]=obj;
    size++;
}
```

Say my array is

> 4 5 7 11 12 13

i say replace what is is position 1 with 3, I get

> 4 3 7 11 12 13

but what I want is

> 4 3 5 7 11 12 13

Comment: you can use System.arrayCopy() method

Comment: No shizzle my question is misundestood. Let me edit it.

Comment: Is `store` an Object[] ?

Comment: yes I am trying to make own arrayList.

Comment: Can you use other libraries, such as Apache Commons?

Comment: If not, think of it this way: (1) Place the values from `store` into a separate Object[] from the beginning up to the index specified. (2) Store the remainder of `store` into a second Object[] (3) Create a temp Object[] (4) Copy first half into this new Object[] (5) Insert new Object (6) Copy the other half into new Object[] (7) Set `store` = the temp array. Look at `System.arrayCopy` as suggested as well

Comment: Ok Ascalonian I will try what you propose.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using magic numbers (`<= 4`), try to make your method base itself off the `store` array. Additionally, it seems that you're attempting to make the class auto-expanding, and if you're doing that, then I think you should look into using a `Map` rather than an array (What if I want an object at index 0 and 99999?).

Answer (score 0):

Use [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) to copy the contents from the original array to the newly created (larger) array.

Answer (score 0):

You say your double array size works, then start at the index where you want to put the new element, start there and move everything over one spot, then add your new element where you want it.